# Questions on Visual Studio Code

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

There are currently over 2,000 questions on [Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode), a code editing application made by Microsoft. The tag description is:

> Visual Studio Code is a source code and text editor for Linux, OS X,
> and Windows. It includes support for debugging, embedded Git Control,
> and rich development experiences such as intelligent code completion.
> It is developed by Microsoft and is available for free.

I use it and like it, but do questions about VS Code really belong on Stack Overflow, or do they belong on Super User? The vast majority of questions are about the application itself; usage, configuration, errors, etc., not specific code questions. Some titles:

- VSCODE error: “phpcs: Unable to locate phpcs.”
- connect external language server to vs code extension
- how to move a file to another folder in vscode?
- Find All References - Visual Studio Code
- VSCode: how to display both output window and debug console?

I'm often tempted to close questions under this tag as off-topic thinking they belong on Super User, but wasn't sure if I was approaching this correctly.

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. " so depending on the reading of this close reason you can yes it is off-topic as it is "general computing software" or you can say no it is a tool used used primarly for programming... But when it's a meta question about this tool...

Comment: VSC is a software development tool, so questions about it are on-topic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Visual Studio Code is a *"software tool commonly used by programmers"*, so it fits one of the three *"or"* criteria. Since it's a code editor, I think it's safe to assume that most, if not all, questions also fit the fourth criteria.

As anecdotal evidence (is that the correct term?): we also allow questions about other IDEs such as [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) and [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), or general purpose tools such as [notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) if the problem is related to software development.

Comment: 101k questions about eclipse, oh the humanity, won't someone please think of the children!

Comment: I think question about tools is very important for developers